# How can I stop/cancel a workflow with an error message when a directory does not exists?

Tags: github, github-actions

I know in a bash script I can check for exitance of a directory:

```
if [ -d "/path/to/dir" ] 
then
    echo "Directory /path/to/dir exists." 
else
    echo "Error: Directory /path/to/dir does not exists."
fi
```

How can I use an expression like `[ -d "/path/to/dir" ]` to stop/cancel a workflow with an error message when a directory does not exists?

Comment: Does below answers help you or there is still sth not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Check folder
      run: |
        if [ -d "/path/to/dir" ] 
        then
            echo "Directory /path/to/dir exists."
            
        else
            echo "Error: Directory /path/to/dir does not exists."
            throw "Error: Directory /path/to/dir does not exists."
        fi
```

Please be aware that `/path/to/dir` refers to root directory and if you want to check presence of the folder from folder where code is checked out then use `path/to/dir`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your workflow steps exits nonzero, then the workflow will stop.  So you can do something like this:

```
[ -d "path/to/dir" ] || { echo "Error: path does not exist" >&2; false; }
```

Note that you will want to quote this appropriately if you put it directly in the workflow file, probably using single quotes.  Note that if you are using a Windows target, you'll need to specify `bash` as the shell.